# (MUI/NextJS) Grid container minHeight doesn't work when wrapped in form

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to wrap a Grid within an HTML form with MUI/React (with NextJS, if that matters).  The minHeight attribute works if the grid isn't wrapped in the form, but when it is wrapped in the form, it shrinks to the size of the children.  I'm using `<form/>` because I'm trying to use MUI w/ `react-hook-form`.

The following minHeight works:

```
return <Grid container minHeight='100%'>
  {items}
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't:

```
return <form style={{minHeight: '100%'}}>
  <Grid container minHeight='100%'>
    {items}
  </Grid>
</form
```

Any ideas about what's going on?  Do forms not work like other dom elements?  Thanks.